# how to post data from Unity3D_WebGL to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, unity-game-engine, http-post

i build a Unity3d WebGL Game

Before build , my post function is work

after that i only get null response

```
    IEnumerator Upload(List<PostData> _sd, string _work_type)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    for(int i = 0; i < _sd.Count; i++)
    {
        form.AddField(_sd[i].v1, _sd[i].v2);
    }
    WWW getData = new WWW(MyServerUrl, form);
    yield return getData;
    if (getData.error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log(getData.text);
    }
    string srcString = getData.text;
    result = srcString;
    }
}
```

How to fix this?

*edit
i use unity official example , use UnityWebRequest to post the data

```
    IEnumerator Upload()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("type", "Login");
    form.AddField("username", "game_test");
    form.AddField("password", "123456");


    //using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://dicegameweb.azurewebsites.net/WEB/Handles.aspx", form))
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost:2525/WEB/Handles.aspx", form))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
```

this is code after edit

Comment: Check if you got any error with `Debug.Log(getData.error)`.

Comment: but i need bulid to webgl first , how to Debug.Log when i bulid the webgl?

Comment: Add a UI text component then use it to show the error

Comment: mm , I tried it.
but still null

Comment: Log `getData.error` not `getData.text`

Comment: i change code like this         if (getData.error != null)
        {
            tt.text += getData.error+",";
            Debug.Log(getData.text);
        }

Comment: it's still show nothing

Comment: i change the code , i use UnityWebRequest to do post , and i get the error , but ui text only show the "Unknown Error"

Comment: How about `UnityWebRequest.responseCode`?

Comment: Null , show nothing

Comment: `UnityWebRequest.responseCode` is not a string and therefore cannot show null or nothing.

Comment: i thought that means "response" , i check again

Comment: in the UnityEdit , responseCode=200
in the WebGl , responseCode = 0

Comment: Please edit your question and post the UnityWebRequest code just like you did for your WWW code. Also show how you're calling the coroutine function function.

Comment: ok , is edited , in the bottom

Comment: Is the WebGL game hosted on the-same server you are making the request to? If the answer is no, I suggest you set `UnityWebRequest.chunkedTransfer` to false before the request. `www.chunkedTransfer = false`

Comment: mmm, it try www.chunkedTransfer = false , but look like even not change the text, may be i should hosted on same server , and try again?

Comment: i try hosted same server on azure , then the script using www is success get the post response , but i stille don't know how it happened , anyway, thank you for helping me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

host two web on same server an same server , then post can work